# How to interpret the Shapley formula

Tags: shapley

For the Shapley equation
[image: \begin{equation} \phi_{i} = \sum_{S\subseteq F\backslash {i}}\dfrac{|S|!(|F| - |S| - 1)!}{|F|!}\left[f_{S\cup{i}}(x_{S\cup{i}})-f_{S}(x_{S})\right] \end{equation}]

How to read [image] ??

I know the first part says F is a subset of S, but what does the \{i} mean?

Comment: It's the other way around: `S` is a subset of `F` (the superset goes on the right-hand-side of the **⊆** symbol).

Comment: `F\{i}` is [set difference, or relative complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement), a set of all elements of `F` except `i`.  `S` is subset of or equal to that set, not `F`, because of precedence: `S⊆(F\{i})`. For example, if `F` is `{1, 2, 3}` and `i` is `2`, then `S⊆{1, 3}`. However, this is not on-topic for Stack Overflow, as it has nothing to do with programming: this is mathematics.

Comment: @Amadan, thanks for your answer.  I looked for the Mathematics forum but only saw "mathematics of teachers".  I thought that the `Shapley` topic will allow my question to fall in Stack Overflow.  You are correct though.  Is there a Mathematics forum in Stackoverflow except that one for Mathematics teachers?  Thanks again!

Comment: [maths.SE]: "Mathematics Stack Exchange is for people studying mathematics _at any level_ and professionals in related fields." (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to sum over all coalitions where agent i is not present. In this notation it is denoted by F \ {i}.

The interpretation of the Shapley value:

- Take a coalition where agent i is not present.
- Add agent i and calculate the increase of the coalition value: value of the coalition after agent i joined minus value of the coalition when agent i was not in the coalition. This is agent i's marginal cost/value of joining this coalition.
- Multiply this by the specified weight.
- Do all these steps for all coalitions where agent i is not present and sum the weighted marginal costs/values: hence the notation you are asking about.